# Why doesn't this .push work? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "some text jjke kjerk jker helmi kjekjr helmi ekjrkje helmi";
var myName = "helmi";
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === 'h') {
    for (var j = i; j < text[i] + myName.length; j+=1) {
        }
    hits.push('text[j]');
        }
    };

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

I want it to find "myName" in the "text", and push it. But it only pushes whatever I put in the parenthesis after hits.push. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `hits.push(text[j])` - no quotes.

Comment: You're pushing a String literal containing "text[j]". Try `hits.push(text[j]);` instead.

Comment: Also: `if (!text.match(/\bhelmi\b/)) console.log('not found')` – there are better ways to find text in text than double loops.

Comment: Also, your code is not generic too, it may not work if the value of text is changed

Answer (score 1):

> But it only pushes whatever I put in the parenthesis after hits.push

Exactly, which is why you don't want to put a string in there:

```
hits.push('text[j]');
```

but a variable value:

```
hits.push(text[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === 'h') {

       for (var j = i; j < text[i] + myName.length; j+=1) {        
       hits.push(text[j]);
       }      
   }
```

your code has bracket problem and in some case you're doing wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function. It gives you an opportunity to check your name word by word instead of checking your name character by character.

```
var text = "some text jjke kjerk jker helmi kjekjr helmi ekjrkje helmi";
var myName = "helmi";
var hits = [];

var texts = text.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
    if (texts[i] === myName) {
        hits.push(texts[i]);
    }
}

if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else {
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for what you are trying to do is

```
if(text.indexOf(myName)!=-1)
   console.log(myName);
else
   console.log("Your name wasn't found");
```